# add class based on value

Tags: php, html, show-hide

I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="check">feature: {value}</div>
```

Between brackets is a shortcode that can either be 'yes' or 'no'.
The php responsible for this value is:

```
if($get_value==1){
            $replace='yes';
        }else{
            $replace='no';
        }
```

What I want to achieve is that the entire div is hidden whenever the value is 'no'.
Maybe a class could be added when the value is no that enables me to hide the div with CSS? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php

$value = "no";
?>
```

**CSS**

```
.hideMe {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML & PHP** *(One Liner)*

```
<div class="<?=($value=='yes'?'':'hideMe')?>">feature: {value}</div>
```

---

When the value of  `$value` is `yes`, the class will be empty. 
When the value of  `$value` is `no`, the class will be `hideMe`.

Comment: the beauty of ternary

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**CSS**

```
div.no {
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="check <?php echo $replace; ?>">feature: <?php echo $get_value; ?></div>
```